# Increment all the values in linked list nodes with a constant time complexity

Tags: linked-list, pseudocode

Is there any way to update all values in linked list nodes increment by some value, say 1 by constant time complexity ?

I tried defining global value then when retrieving we can update the value but value in the node does not update in that method.

Comment: Please, provide some code to find out why the update you talked about didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a thing is possible, as all nodes need to be updated. On the other hand, as you mentioned in your question, you may accept something say "delayed update" or "incremental update" to lowering the operation cost of your linked-list. But, you should consider that this may limit your custom linked-list usage scenarios (it becomes a non-standard linked-list).